# Unupvoted answer

Tags: support, voting

One of my answers just got un-upvoted. That's fine, I have no problem with that. However, I am aware that there are restrictions on retracting votes based on how long it has been since either the vote was placed or the post was edited. I just tested with a recent vote of mine, and it was denied because it has been two hours.

The most recent upvote on this post is ~1 month old, and that was one day after the last edit on the post. There have been no edits to it since, and my reputation history shows no upvotes since then either.

How could this upvote be undone?

Comment: It is possible that the vote was placed before the most recent edit.  That would make it eligible to be retracted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug/problematic feature: [Undone edits disappear from revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133314/166936). It's slated to be fixed. It's possible that someone edited, voted, and removed their edit, causing the revision to disappear, while the vote was allowed to be retracted.

Note that this isn't considered acceptable behavior; votes are anonymous and it's perfectly fine that no one knows that you voted/unvoted/switched votes, however posts should *not* be silently edited in order to play with votes like this.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's been stated [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/372/98) and [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/371/accidental-downvote-what-to-do#comment1008_371), that an edit -- a substantial one -- *can* be used to justify removing a vote, so long as the edit is *substantial* and this isn't done too often. This is of course different than what Rarity refers to, where an edit is actually rolled back afterwards. That's just abuse ;)